# How to convert excel dates dd/mm/yy into number format such as 01011994

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me with an excel formula or any alternate ways on how i can **convert a date like 01/01/1994 into number output '01011994'**; i found the reverse method of this but couldn't find the methods i require.

Thank you

Comment: This is the reverse of converting 10 digit integers into dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date is in cell A1 then this formula will do the trick:

```
=TEXT(DAY(A1),"00")&TEXT(MONTH(A1),"00")&YEAR(A1)
```

The DAY/MONTH/YEAR function will extract the digits, and the TEXT function will put leading zeros in front of the DAY and MONTH if necessary.

Comment: Hey the formula didnt work; i have 01/01/1950 in a2, i put the formula in b2 changed day(a1) to (a2) etc...

Comment: So what result did the formula give you?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-date-to-julian-format this worked!

Comment: The problem was probably because I used a semi-colon in the TEXT formula, changing this to a comma should fix the issue. I've edited the answer to be a comma. I wrote the answer from a PC that used semi-colon as a list separator instead of the (more common) comma.

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept it, so that other users can see it has been answered successfully. When you get enough rep, you can also upvote answers (not just the accepted one) if you want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "01/01/1994" value is in `A1`, you can use this formula:

```
=RIGHT((DAY(A1) + 100); 2) & RIGHT((MONTH(A1) + 100); 2) & YEAR(A1)
```

Comment: Hey the formula didnt work; i have 01/01/1950 in a2, i put the formula in b2 changed day(a1) to (a2) etc...

Comment: Seeing comments below the DeanOC's answer, I guess it's the same for mine: replace semi-colons by commas if it's what your own configuration requires.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is today try the below Formula

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"dmmyyyy")
```

If your date is in E7 then try the below Formula

```
=LEFT(E7,2)&MID(E7,4,2)&RIGHT(E7,4)
```